# Ramda format array of objects based on propvalues

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How to convert the array of objects into formatted array of objects as shown below.

```
var a = 
[{"id": "001","project": "one","projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"},
{"id": "001","project": "one","projectstartDate": "10/15/2018"},
{"id": "001","project": "two","projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"},
{"id": "002","project": "one","projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"},
{"id": "002","project": "two","projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"}]
```

need help to group and zip using id then by project prop values

```
[
    {
        "name" : "001",
        "data" : [{
                "name" : "one",
                "data" : [ 
                    {"projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"},
                    {"projectstartDate": "10/15/2018"}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "two",
                "data" : [ {"projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"}]
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        "name" : "002",
        "data" : [
            {
                "name" : "one",
                "data" : [ {"projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"}]
            },
            {
                "name" : "two",
                "data" : [ {"projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"}]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Tried

```
R.pipe(R.groupBy(R.prop('id')),R.map(R.groupBy(R.prop('project'))))(a)
```

Grouped according but I need by name prop and data props.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While `groupBy` can be the workhorse of this, there is much more going on in your transformation.  `groupBy` simply creates an object with keys generated by the function passed to it and values consisting of arrays of all elements that generate that particular key.  It's useful, but usually has to be combined with other things.  In your case, you want to turn that into objects with `name` and `data` properties and, in those data objects, you want to remove that key field.

Moreover you want to do this twice: once on the initial array for the `id` property, and then again on the new `data` arrays for their `project` properties.  So we should create a reusable function that will do that for us, calling it on the initial data and then on the `data` properties the first one generates.

Here is a Ramda solution that does this:

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, prop, toPairs, map, over, lensIndex, dissoc, zipObj, lensProp} = R

const groupInto = (name) => pipe(
  groupBy(prop(name)),
  toPairs,
  map(over(lensIndex(1), map(dissoc(name)))),
  map(zipObj(['name', 'data']))
)

const reformat = pipe(
  groupInto('id'),
  map(over(lensProp('data'), groupInto('project')))
)

const a = [
  {id: "001", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
  {id: "001", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/15/2018"},
  {id: "001", project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"},
  {id: "002", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
  {id: "002", project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"}
]

console.log(reformat(a))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

`dissoc(name)` returns a near-clone of an object, missing only the `name` property.  `over(lensIndex(1), fn)` replaces the object at index 1 with the result of calling `fn` on that object.  Similarly, `over(lensProp('data', fn)` replaces the value of property `data` with the result of calling `fn` on that property.  (In both cases, "replace" is really returing a near-clone again.  Ramda does not mutate user data.)  `zipObj` is best described by an example: `zipObj(['a', 'b'], [1, 2]) //=> {a: 1, b: 2}`

To my mind this is one of the areas where Ramda shines.  (Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author.)  Once you know what these various functions themselves do, this is a very readable description of how to solve the problem, with little extraneous material.

Note what `groupInto` itself does:

```
groupInto('id')(a) //=> [
//  {
//    name: '001'
//    data: [
//      {project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
//      {project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/15/2018"},
//      {project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"}
//    ],
//  },
//  {
//    name: "002"
//    data: [
//      {project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
//      {project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"}
//    ],
//  }
//]
```

Running it again for "project" on each of the `data` properties of the result gives our final answer.

#### Update

After building it this way, and using Ramda to break down the problem, I now feel comfortable writing it without Ramda, and the code isn't as bad as I expected:

```js
const groupInto = (name) => (a) => Object.entries(a.reduce(
  (acc, {[name]: id, ...rest}) => ((acc[id] || (acc[id] = [])).push(rest), acc), 
  {}
)).map(([a, b]) => ({name: a, data: b}))

const format = (a) => groupInto('id')(a).map(
  ({name, data}) => ({name, data: groupInto('project')(data)})
)

var a = [
  {id: "001", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
  {id: "001", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/15/2018"},
  {id: "001", project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"},
  {id: "002", project: "one", projectstartDate: "10/12/2018"},
  {id: "002", project: "two", projectstartDate: "10/14/2018"}
]

console.log(format(a))
```

This has the same breakdown as above, and the process is much the same.  To me, the code is significantly less readable.  But it's also not horrible.  You might have to refactor a bit if your target environment does not include `Object.entries`; that shouldn't be too hard.

But it's only after I used Ramda's tools to build the first approach that the second was easy to write.  Ramda's `pipe` really helps me to think about the problem.

Comment: Thanks scott, I go with the first solution, it's simple to understand